# split a double into parts - matlab

Tags: matlab, date, split

I have a date vector in form

20140117

20130325

20130530

etc.
There are 5,000,000 lines in the double vector.
How can I transfer it to a datevector recognized by matlab?

I don't like changing it to string and putting the parts in separately. It takes too long!

Please Help!

Comment: Do you mean these `20140117` etc... are already numbers and not string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to avoid casting to string then back to number then you can use this method:

```
D = [20140117; 20130325; 20130530];

YY = fix( D./10000 ) ;
MM = fix( (D-YY.*10000) /100 ) ;
DD = fix( (D-YY.*10000-MM.*100 ) );

DateInMatlabformat = datenum( YY , MM , DD ) ;
```

You can package that in a one liner if you want, but basically what it does is:

- Divide by 10000 to get the year in the variable `YY`
- Remove this part from your original date (`(D-YY.*10000)`), then divide by 100 to get the month.
- remove all of that, you obtain the day.

The last line merge all of that in a Matlab standard time serial format. Read the doc on [`datenum`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) and [`datestr`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) for more information.

Comment: good one, I was looking at the possible need for floor instead of round, but for date this seems just fine.

Comment: @qmeeeeeee, yes, whenever I have to round numbers I always have to stop a second and think which `round`,`floor`,`ceil`, or `fix` is the best for the application. Although in this case i'm sure it would even work without any of that. one single division by a power of 10 does not introduce much error...

Comment: To cause an error in splitting, it would require `DD` or `MM` to be above 50. As both can't happen it does not matter in this case. To split digits `fix` should be used, as it rounds towards zero.

Comment: @Daniel. Thanks for the correction. Obviously I didn't "stop and think" long enough in this case because I deemed it too simple. It shows that they are never too simple.

Answer (score 4):

a combination of `fix` and `mod` let's you extract the digits you want:

```
%Matrix Columns YY,MM,DD,hh,mm,ss
[mod(fix(x/10000),100000),mod(fix(x/100),100),mod(x,100),zeros(size(x,1),3)]
%datenum
datenum(mod(fix(x/10000),10000),mod(fix(x/100),100),mod(x,100))
```

Comment: Nice compact one. Stupid me I forgot the `mod` ... (_even though I use it almost everyday_).